# Returning from DRF serializers' create method without actually creating any instance

Tags: django-rest-framework, transactions

I have a situation where on certain exception case, I should continue catch the error and continue the execution of the code. Currently my code looks like this:

```
s = TestSerializer(...)
if s.is_valid():
   instance = s.save()
perform_some_query() # Django yells here



class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except SomeError as err:
            if this_is_the_super_exotic_case:
                return None # Don't shout, just continue silently and don't create an object
            raise
```

The problem is that Django yells at me when executing `perform_some_query()` (see line 3 of the code snippet), saying that:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block. What is the reason for this?
```

Comment: Maybe we can handle that in validation itself ? That way create will be cleaner

Comment: Well, in validation we can either raise an exception or modify the data somehow so that it becomes valid, right? But my goal is just to ignore such records